# $C(\textbf{R})$ is a vector subspace of $\textbf{R}^\textbf{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do I see that $C(\textbf{R})$ is a vector subspace of $\textbf{R}^\textbf{R}$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: What do you mean by $C(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$. To check if a subset $\mathcal W\subset \mathcal V$ is a subspace of $\mathcal V$ it is sufficient to check:

- $0\in \mathcal W$
- $v,w\in\mathcal W\implies v+w\in\mathcal W$ for all $v,w\in\mathcal W$
- $v\in\mathcal W, a\in\mathbb F\implies a\cdot v\in\mathcal W$ for all $v\in\mathcal W,a\in\mathbb F$

In this case you have $\mathcal V=\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{R}}$ and $\mathcal W=C(\mathbf{R})$ (which I assume to be the set of all continuous functions $f:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$). Now apply your knowledge about continuous functions (e.g. the sum of two continuous functions) to check if $\mathcal W$ is a subspace of $\mathcal V$.